# Is it illegal to head to public but hidden web pages such as admin.php?

Tags: hacking, ethical-hacking

I'm someone who's recently been interested in cybersecurity. I learned that most webpages have a text file called robots.txt (like example.com/robots.txt) that holds webpages that are public but are not allowed to show up in search engines, like google.

I don't try hacking these websites, but I like practicing what I learned and going to robots.txt, and once in a while I'll actually come to the admin page (like example.com/admin.php) However, if I were a hacker, this would be something that I could use to hack in... except that I don't try. I don't even put in anything in the password space. I just exit.

I want to know... is this illegal, even though it's technically exposed to the public? I know they can see my IP address and I'd like to not be on a watchlist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[brazil](/questions/tagged/brazil)

No.

Brazilian criminal law recognizes computer hacking as a crime, but only when the perpetrator aims to obtain, alter or destroy data, or install exploits. If your intent is purely academic, and there is no security feature whatsoever, this cannot be a crime under Brazilian law.